# Can I pass a class selector to JavaScript from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have a huge UI with over 10,000 `div` elements (for an experiment I am doing). I would like to find a super fast selector method that should be very raw vanilla JS.

My 10,000+ `div`s are big containers with a class of `.b0` - `.b123` (large number) holding smaller `img`s, each image has a class of `.q0` - `.q100`

I would like to know If I can somehow get the container `div` of an image clicked in a jQuery event handler using my line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( e.target.className.replace( 'q', 'b' ) )[0];
```

where `e` would be the jQuery event.

Or would there be a faster way?

Comment: Did you try it, should work ?

Comment: There's just one thing, the className shouldn't contain any periods, and it looks like you're getting the exact same element that you already have in `e.target` ?

Comment: try what, the method i have listed searches the entire document

Comment: no because they click an image inside a div the target is currently the image but the whole doc must be searched, somehow i need to use the div the image is in to make the search quicker

Comment: Of course it does, that's the `document` part that it starts with, what where you expecting ?

Comment: If you're using a listener on the document there is testing to ensure the target is what you want. If it is you can just do `$this = e.target` if you have the listener on the elements themselves `this` already pertains to the element clicked on. We'll need to know how you are listening to the events

Comment: jQuery click function

Comment: Also jQuery is JavaScript so whatever jQuery does it is possible with raw js. JQuery is a framework built from javascript and to be honest a slower one at that.

Comment: 8DK on what though document or elements

Comment: Clarification: (through whatever method you're using...) `e.target` is currently referring to an `img` element, right? And you're trying to get it's parent `div`? Wouldn't `e.target.parentNode` work for that situation?

Comment: you are correct i think

Comment: If that's what the user wanted then hell to me lol. I guess the whole post has no clarity

Comment: If that's what the user wanted then hell to me lol. I guess the whole post has no clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM up/down traversal is relatively simple in Javascript (of which JQuery is).

Elements can access their parent via [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode)

```
element.parentNode
```

and parents can access their children via [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.childNodes)

```
element.childNodes
```

So accessing your image's parent (where your image is in `e.target`) would be

```
e.target.parentNode
```

Answer (score -1):

Event delegation on the document (or any other element higher up in the tree that holds the elements you want)

This will add a class to the img that is clicked on.

based on the jQuery example you were given it would look like this

```
$(document).on("click", "img", function(){
    var img = $(this);
    img.toggleClass("selected");
});
```

The JavaScript equivalent of that is using the target

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    if (elem.tagName === "img") {
        elem.classList.toggle("selected");
    }
});
```